# How to extract or export rules from SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

Appriciate if I can get help for the below scenario. My issues to identify how to extract/export all java rules on SonarQube 4.5.7. I tried the below two API calls but I get a "The page you were looking for doesn't exist".

The sonarqube version I have shows 781 java rules my objective is to extract them to an excel or a csv file

[1]curl -X GET -v -u admin:admin http://localhost:9000/api/rules?language=java

[2]curl -X GET -v -u admin:admin http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search?languages=java >> java.json

The second option seems to generate an output but not all 781 rules are extracted
thanks,shavantha

Answer (score 11):

URL `api/rules/search?languages=java` is the correct way to get all Java rules. Response is paginated, so only 10 rules are returned by default :

`{
  "total": 781,
  "p": 1,
  "ps": 10,
  "rules": [ <here are 10 rules ]
}`

Use pagination parameter `p` (page index) for traversing all results. Note that the page size can be changed with parameter `ps` (defaults 10).

Comment: thank you it worked. I used REST client on add-on on firefox and extracted the details as : http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search?language=java&p=2&ps=100

Answer (score 5):

Login as an Admin

then go to the Quality Profiles section

click which language rule set you want to copy

click on the settings like button at the side

then select copy and give a name to the copy

then in the next page click on the settings like button
then click backup

your file will be exported in to your local in the XML format

**Applicable for both Internet Sonar as well as Local**

Comment: The real answer. Any way to upload the xml to another Sonar instance?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried that one.., if you have done pls post that one..,

Comment: @BrandonDyer yes, similarly you can login as admin and go tot Quality Profile. There are 2 buttons on top right side, Create & Restore. The XML file generated in previous step(from other or same SQ instance) can be uploaded using Restore button.

Comment: Thanks @VigneshRavichandran , for this solution I was able to export all profiles.

Comment: Thanks @TusharK , thanks for the method to restore. It worked for me and I could update my Sonar

Answer (score 2):

http://localhost:9000/api/rules/search?languages=java

the url parameter is languages rather language